# MySqli Error: Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements (current value: 16382)

Tags: c#, mysqli

Muy buenas, tengo este error recurrente que sucede con un código que NO ES MIO.
Hasta donde se el programa está hecho en C# y no tengo acceso (por ahora) al codigo.

El error es temporal, y solo hace que el programa se detenga hasta reiniciarlo.
Pero obvio, no quiero estar haciendo eso cada vez que sucede el problema.

Lo que necesito son guías primeramente.

- ¿Qué significa este error?
- ¿Cómo ocurre este error?
- ¿Cómo se puede solucionar?

Hasta ahora la única guía que he encontrado está este link: 
-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39588167/mysqli-error-cant-create-more-than-max-prepared-stmt-count-statements-current/52252910

Al parecer son demasiadas consultas preparadas, lo que en teoría es correcto, el programa hasta donde se, corre un loop, el cual no se estaría reiniciando por si solo.

En una respuesta dicen que hay que cerrar la consulta, pero no se como se hace eso.

---

He conseguido acceso a la función del código, solo he censurado lo necesario para analizar el error.

```
static void principal()
{
    rut_produccion.Clear();
    HasRows();
    int cuenta_ruts = rut_produccion.Count();
    for (int pasar = 0; pasar < cuenta_ruts; pasar++)
    {
        rutempresa = rut_produccion[pasar];
        char c = rutempresa[0];
        if (c == '7' || c != '7')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Revisando Rut: " + rutempresa);
            string query = "SELECT * from log_descarga WHERE rut=@rut_empresa && copiada='0' && descargada='1' && clave not like '%vacio%'";
            if (OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //Create Command
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conexion);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rut_empresa", rut_produccion[pasar]);
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    boletas.Add(reader.GetString(1));
                }
                reader.Close();
                conexion.Close();
            }

            int numero_boletas = boletas.Count();

            for (int i = 0; i < numero_boletas; i++)
            {
                string[] h = boletas[i].Split('/');
                string path = @ruta + "\\temp\\" + h[0] + "/" + h[1] + "/" + h[2] + "/" + h[3] + "/";
                try
                {
                    if (Directory.Exists(path))
                    {
                        //...
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                        Console.WriteLine("\nGenerando Directorio " + path);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ee)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
                    Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0],
                    Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1]);
                    conexion.Close();
                    // close current process
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }

                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Copiando " + boletas[i]);
                    System.IO.File.Copy(@ruta + "\\respaldo2\\" + boletas[i], @ruta + "\\temp\\" + boletas[i], true);
                    string connectionString = @"datos_censurados";
                    conexion = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                    conexion.Open();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = conexion;
                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE  log_descarga SET copiada='1' WHERE clave like'" + boletas[i] + "'";
                    cmd.Prepare();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rut_empresa", rutempresa);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conexion.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ee)
                {
                    Console.Write("Press <Enter> to exit... " + ee);
                    while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Enter) { }
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
                    Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0],
                    Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1]);
                    conexion.Close();
                    // close current process
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
            }

            if (numero_boletas > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    string connectionString = @"datos_censurados";
                    MySqlConnection connection = null;
                    conexion = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                    conexion.Open();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = conexion;
                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE rut_declarar SET nuevo='1' WHERE rut=@rut_empresa";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rut_empresa", rutempresa);
                    cmd.Prepare();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conexion.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ee)
                {
                    Console.Write("Press <Enter> to exit... " + ee);
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
                    Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0],
                    Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1]);
                    conexion.Close();
                    // close current process
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
            }

        }
        boletas.Clear();
    }
    Console.Clear();
    rut_produccion.Clear();
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
    Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0],
    Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1]);
    conexion.Close();
    // close current process
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que está diciendo el error es que se están creando ¡16382 consultas preparadas en ese código!  Aunque el código no sea tuyo, ¿no tienes acceso a él? Muéstranos el código y quizá podremos ver el error, casi seguro que las consultas se preraran en un bucle, lo cual no tiene sentido. Deberían prepararse una sola vez, fuera del bucle, y dentro del bucle, a lo sumo, hacer las ejecuciones.

Comment: He agregado el código de la función en donde termina produciéndose el problema.

Comment: Parece ser que es justo lo que sospechaba. Tienes un bucle `for` dentro del cual preparas una y otra vez la consulta. El `prepare` debería ir fuera del bucle.

Comment: Se prepara dentro del for, por que es donde se terminan obteniendo los datos necesarios. Pero si se prepara eso dentro del for, como puedo cerrar ese proceso ?

Comment: Ya, el problema es que **en las consultas preparadas tú deberías poner marcadores, no lo datos en sí mismos** y luego al ejecutar pasas los valores que sustituirían a los marcadores. De modo que en esta consulta por ejemplo: `cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE  log_descarga SET copiada='1' WHERE clave like'" + boletas[i] + "'";` deberías cambiar la parte de `boletas[i]` por un marcador, y ya dentro del bulce haces binding de `boletas[i]`. Así de paso evitas estar preparando siempre la consulta y que te inyecten SQL.